# Remote debuging on Pycharm is concatenating local and remote path

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to.

I'm trying to debug a Python program running on a Raspberry Pi. The source code is located on my PC.

I set up an FTPS deployment and remote interpreter over ssh.

When I just run the app on the remote Raspberry Pi there are no problems.

The problem appears while I try to set up a breakpoint. In this case pydev writes:

```
>pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist:
/home/pi/python/f:/python projects/server/server.py (will have no effect)
```

Pycharm thinks that the path to the app is the path on the remote computer + the path on the local computer.

Does anyone know what setting might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 17):

From [Run/Debug Configuration: Python](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-python.html) section of PyCharm 3.4.0 Web Help:

> Path mappings –
>   This field appears, if a remote interpreter has been
>   selected in the field Python interpreter. Click the browse button
>   to define the required mappings between the local and
>   remote paths. In the Edit Path Mappings dialog box, use add/delete
>   buttons to create new mappings, or delete the selected ones.

Configuring this option in your debug configuration should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's obvious, but I was getting the same problem when using `~` instead of writing out the whole path of my home directory for the remote mapping.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10910635)

Comment: Apologies. Ideally I wanted to leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points so I thought it was the next best option.